# Qt adding dll and lib files to a project

Tags: qt, dll, lib

I'm trying to include some library files to my Qt project. Its structure looks like this:

- project.pro
- libs\x64

  - file1.dll
  - file2.dll
  - file2.lib

I tried editing the `LIBS` variable in the .pro file, but I still get error `cannot open file 'xxx.lib` (or xxx.dll, depending what I tried in th e.pro file).

I tried adding the files like this:

```
LIBS += -Llibs\x64
LIBS += -lfile1
LIBS += -lfile2
```

or like this:

```
LIBS += libs\x64\file1.dll
LIBS += libs\x64\file2.lib
LIBS += libs\x64\file2.dll
```

whatever I tried, I got the error that a dll/lib file cannot be opened. So how can I add these files to my project?

Comment: Try right click on the project name - > add library

Comment: @JLev I tried and there's still the same error: `cannot open file file2.lib`.

Comment: Since when can you add a dll to your project? Isn't that only located and loaded on statup of your app?

Comment: @MartinHennings I'm not really sure what I'm doing, but I found it here: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_link_to_a_dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/libs/x64" -file1
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/libs/x64" -file2
```

The libs should go to the folder described, where $$PWD is the folder of the .pro file, and the dll-s should go next to the .exe file.
Also don't forget to run qmake afterwards.

Comment: And what should I do about the .dll files? Just left them in the directory with the .lib files? I tried your suggestion, it seems that it found the .lib files (I don't get the above error anymore), but I got lots of Unresolved external symbol errors now (for symbols from the libraries I'm trying to include).

Comment: Hey Poe, did you figure out the issue? I'm struggling with something similar.

Comment: The dll-s should go next to the .exe file, but missing those would not result in unresolved external symbol error at build.  In that case you should only have an issue at the start of running the program.